# Convergence and divergence $\lim_{r \to \infty} r^t$

Tags: calculus, limits

For what values of $t$ is $$\lim_{r \to \infty} r^t$$ convergent and divergent?

This is easy, but my head is messed up: what happens when $t=0$? I want to say:

- for $t>0$ it is divergent.
- for $t<0$ it is convergent.
- for $t=0$ ?

(note to self: pb2 s278)

Comment: What is $2^0$, $e^0$, $3^0$?

Comment: Are you worried about $\infty^{0}$?

Comment: Since for all $r\in ]o, \infty[$ one has $r^0=1$, the limit equals $\lim \limits_{r\to \infty}(1)$.

Comment: so the classic $anything ^0 = 1$ holds?

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question and moreso a comment:

Yes, the rule of $r^0 = 1$ holds here. After all, if $t=0$ then, for $r$ large enough, there is no issue in claiming $r^0 = 1$. Therefore,

$$\lim_{r \to \infty} r^t \;\overset{t=0}= \; \lim_{r \to \infty} r^0 = \lim_{r \to \infty} 1 = 1$$

Therefore, it clearly converges, and thus the limit converges for $t \le 0$. This is even clearer if you imagine making a table of values or a plot: let $r=1,2,3,4$ and so on; $r^0=1$ no matter how large.

(Of course it is noteworthy that $r^0$ is not always $1$; sometimes it's undefined. $0^0$ is the case for such. However, since we're considering a limit that's going to infinity, we don't have to worry about that.)